# X-Pad: avoid browser bug header added by apache

Tags: header, apache2

I see this header appended to the response from apache. Does it have any significance in new age browsers; or it's merely there to circumvent a bug in older versions of Netscape. Seems weird.

**EDIT**

I was doing a performance testing on our app, when I saw that in Jmeter response text, there was this weird header that comes back. It said:

```
X-pad: avoid browser bug
```

Thats it!
So I tried some googling, and it seemed like a header added for Netscape browsers' bug. Anyway, I am still curious, that since we are so far away from those versions of browser (thankfully), is there a solid reason that it's still there.
We use apache2.

Hopefully those details help.

Cheers

Comment: This question could seriously benefit with some details -- _What_ header and contents specifically? (The title is difficult to parse. Put content in the _body_ of the question...) -- what version of Apache did you find emit this header? Under what conditions? It seems like a neat find but not nearly the detail that would make it awesome.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that iur sarnold; it was indeed a miss on my part. Added more details here.

Comment: Oh yes, much better, thanks. :)

Comment: Noticed this too when testing my own CLI client.  If you only send the get and host header in the request it returns the X-Pad header in the response.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Nope, it's a vestigial header nowadays; that is to say, it was put there to work around a bug in a browser which is obsolete (several generations older than IE6 - the bug was reported fixed as of 1997, 15 years ago!) and nobody uses it any more.

[The patch to remove it](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-cvs/200812.mbox/%3C20081205051015.456402388879@eris.apache.org%3E) is in Apache's SVN since 2008, but it apparently still hasn't propagated to all distributions (plus some sites may use non-updated versions of Apache).

Here's the comment for the header, picked up [from the source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/http/http_filters.c?r1=722081&r2=723585):

```
/* Navigator versions 2.x, 3.x and 4.0 betas up to and including 4.0b2
 * have a header parsing bug.  If the terminating \r\n occur starting
 * at offset 256, 257 or 258 of output then it will not properly parse
 * the headers.  Curiously it doesn't exhibit this problem at 512, 513.
 * We are guessing that this is because their initial read of a new request
 * uses a 256 byte buffer, and subsequent reads use a larger buffer.
 * So the problem might exist at different offsets as well.
 *
 * This should also work on keepalive connections assuming they use the
 * same small buffer for the first read of each new request.
 *
 * At any rate, we check the bytes written so far and, if we are about to
 * tickle the bug, we instead insert a bogus padding header.  Since the bug
 * manifests as a broken image in Navigator, users blame the server.  :(
 * It is more expensive to check the User-Agent than it is to just add the
 * bytes, so we haven't used the BrowserMatch feature here.
 */
```

Comment: Great response! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know that the answer has been accepted but still I think this would be useful for users running php.

If you're a php user and you're getting this header. You can turn it off using custom "X-Powered-By" header.
 For Example:
`header('X-Powered-By: Powerful Management');` you can also remove it this way 
`header_remove('X-Pad');`, sometimes setting that header to empty also removes it: 
`header('X-Pad:')` 
and bam your X-Pad header will disappear

Comment: I ran into the X-Pad header and (just because I was curious, it doesn't really do any harm) tried to remove it. Your way does NOT work. Sure, if the X-Pad was added in one request and you add the X-Powered-By header, it may be gone for that specific request - because the new header serves as padding now, so the linebreak isn't at position 256/257 anymore. In another request though (that did not have the X-Pad without the new X-Powered-By header), it might now appear because the first linebreak had been shifted to 256 now.

Comment: For me, setting X-Pad to an empty value using PHP (header ('X-Pad :')) worked to get rid of it - Apache seems to accept this and does not override it (it does for some other auto-generated headers like content-length). Can somebody verify this?