# PHP Error message in Firefox not Chrome

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, firefox, browser

One of our websites earlier today started outputting a few PHP warnings that were only visible through Firefox but weirdly the errors wouldn't show in Chrome or Safari.

I had a look at the request/response headers and noticed in the response header for Firefox the entry

```
    X-pad: avoid browser bug
```

Could this be the reason for the discrepancy in between the two browsers? From what I could find, X-pad was a work around for a bug that existed in an ancient browser.

Below is a screenshot of the errors from Firefox.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTUUK.jpg)

Edit.

Found out the cause of the error and also why chrome wasn't showing the warnings. A number of pages on our site had been injected with some code, as documented [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/security-problem-8). The code was ignoring safari and chrome , but not Firefox. Hence the discrepancy.

As for the fix, simply remove any instances of the code. Affected, were instances of index.php/template.php/page.php files.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the live site?. I would like to check if the error appears in the source of both browsers.

Comment: Please paste the error messages as text, not as screenshot. And show line 22 of the file that's throwing the warning about line 22.

Comment: I guess they're still in the source for both, it's just that the browsers render invalid html differently.

Comment: Turn error reporting off for notices or fix the notice. You are accessing a variable or array/string index that is not set before.

Comment: @Maerlyn -Errors only showed up in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized string you get because your variable is not setted in an array. Make sure that is setted.

```
 if (isset($somevar['var']))
 {
      // etc..
 }
```

Your `session_start()` code is NOT on your TOP in a PHP file. A `session_start()` should be called before all scripts executed.

To turn off showing errors manually via PHP put on top:

```
 ini_set("display_errors", 0);
```

Put all your errors to `error.log` file instead of showing errors on PHP production environment.

[X-Pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711584/x-pad-avoid-browser-bug-header-added-by-apache) is header appender to the response from apache. So this isn't way what errors occured. X-Pad doesn't relation with your errors.