# The response of a server receiving a file is automatic or must be manually coded?

Tags: php, ios, xml

I am developing an iPhone application that sends through HTTP requests an XML file to my PHP server.
I have coded my server and got the XML file and stored it in database. Now I want to see from my iPhone if the server got my XML file.
This response of the server, I must code it or is it automatic?
If it is not automatic, how do I make it? I must make the server send back a simple XML to my iPhone stating that everything is "OK" and also program my iPhone application to get the XML?

Comment: Your HTTP response should come [with a code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: If you app needs `XML` back, yes, your server will need to construct and echo it back to your iPhone app.  Then your iPhone app will need to parse that response.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean if it "needs" xml back? I just need somehow to catch a response from the server to be sure that the xml file was sent ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have set up some proper API for your App to query, just use [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). If everything was ok and the data got successfully inserted, reply with a `200` response. If there was an error there are numerous other status codes to send, e.g. `500` internal server error. Your client App can then parse these responses and react appropietly.

Comment: i just get the http request from my server like this : $xml = file_get_contents('php://input'); . Then i parse it and store it in the database. Is this sending back automatically a response to the phone?

Comment: If MySQL doens't return an error then it probably got stored and you can respond with a HTTP 200 Status Code (the default one), when there was an error with Mysql then [send a 500 status code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162223/how-to-send-500-internal-server-error-error-from-a-php-script). Of course this is pretty basic, you can send different codes for malformed input for example