# Set the HTTP content type response to “application/json” in php

Tags: php, json, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have a question. I have the folowing condition :

```
You should return an HTTP 500 status code and more details about the error in the message body. Set the HTTP content type response to “application/json”.The error detail must be in JSON format as described below:

 {
    "ErrorCode" : 402,
    "ErrorMessage" : "Item"
  }
```

I tried like this :

```
if(!Gain::verifyIfUserExistByIdm($aOutput['UserId'])){
    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
    return json_encode(array('ErrorCode'=>407,'ErrorMessage'=>'Error'));
    die();
}
```

But not work, can you help me please? Thx in advance

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Where I need to add this `header`

Comment: I think you want this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162223/how-to-send-500-internal-server-error-error-from-a-php-script, and return is not needed. simply exit; after the header is enough.

Comment: `500` is only for internal servers errors where no other information about the error is available. You should consider using either a more specific `5xx` error code, or use a `4xx` error, if it is a client problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand so for example if I want to send the error 402

Comment: @Gigel - please note you should call header in this way only once and only before any other output

Comment: ah, ok just use the header 
  
header('Content-Type: application/json'); just prior to outputting the data then,

Comment: Not work like this : 
`header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 return json_encode(array('ErrorCode'=>407,'ErrorMessage'=>'Payload decode failed'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to output the JSON (not just return it), and let the client know that the content is JSON by setting the `Content-Type`:

```
// The user does not exist
if ( ! Gain::verifyIfUserExistByIdm($aOutput['UserId'])) {

    // If the user does not exist then "Forbidden" would make sense
    header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");

    // Let the client know that the output is JSON
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    // Output the JSON
    echo json_encode(array(
        'ErrorCode'    => 407,
        'ErrorMessage' => 'Error',
    ));
    // Always terminate the script as soon as possible
    // when setting error headers
    die;
}
```