# problems with encoding json

Tags: javascript, php, json

i have 2 separate host on web , and i use same code in both , and both encode json for me in php .

but one of them in just keep saying this , in my android app :

**This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support**

how could i get rid of this get rid of ? 
why its only in one of my host ?

php code is :

```
<?php

$servername = "sql301.gigfa.com";
$username = "****"; 
$password = "****";
$dbname = "gigfa_18832988_tamrin";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM t;";



$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array("Week"=>$row[0],"Exercise"=>$row[1]));
}
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Check the JS files you're including?

Comment: Whatever it is its nothing to do with this PHP code

Comment: it's looks like browser problem, not php. Check setting of browser and enable javascript there (i don't have much idea about that)

Comment: Try to set the correct header (application/json) while returning the json from PHP. See this stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31522940/688924 It has more descriptive answer as well. Still if you face problem then please let us know how are you retrieving the json output in the client side. It looks like you are trying to use webview. Can't help much until we have more idea on your server, clients.