# PHP Redirect User And Set 403 Header

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This might seem like an odd request, but I'm trying to redirect users away from a particular set of pages and set a `403` header so that my error handler picks up on it and displays the necessary notification. My redirect script is not redirecting users though.

I'm attempting to redirect using this script:

```
// Redirect users from sensative pages
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] !== "admin") {
 $redirect[] = array();
 $redirect[] = "uploadImg.php";
 if (in_array(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), $redirect)) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN');
  header('Status: 403 You Do Not Have Access To This Page');
  header("Location: index.php");
}
}
```

But oddly enough if I remove these two lines:

```
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN');
  header('Status: 403 You Do Not Have Access To This Page');
```

and make the script:

```
// Redirect users from sensative pages
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] !== "admin") {
 $redirect[] = array();
 $redirect[] = "uploadImg.php";
 if (in_array(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), $redirect)) {
  header("Location: index.php");
}
}
```

It redirects the users back to the `index.php` page.

I'm specifically trying to set headers so that my `.htaccess` picks up on the error and performs the error document handling.

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?err=400
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?err=401
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?err=403
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?err=404
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?err=500
ErrorDocument 502 /index.php?err=502
ErrorDocument 504 /index.php?err=504

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^h/(\d+)/w/(\d+)/a/([a-z]+)/thumb/(.+)$ /gallery/thumb.php?h=$1&w=$2&a=$3&src=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^h/(\d+)/w/(\d+)/a/([a-z]+)/watermark/(.+)$ /gallery/watermark.php?h=$1&w=$2&a=$3&src=$4 [L]

<FilesMatch ".(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)$">
ErrorDocument 404 error.png
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://example.com  
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

And finally my error handler script on `index.php`:

```
if(isset($_GET['err'])) {
   $error_status = $_GET['err'];
   switch ($error_status) {
     case 400:
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-top" role="alert">' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<strong>400 Bad Request:</strong> There was an error with your request.' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
     break;

     case 401:
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-top" role="alert">' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<strong>401 UNAUTHORIZED:</strong> You are not authorized to view this page or directory.' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
     break;

     case 403:
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-top" role="alert">' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<strong>403 FORBIDDEN:</strong> You do not have access to this file or directory.' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
     break;

     case 404:
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-top" role="alert">' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<strong>404 Error:</strong> The page you are looking for does not exist.' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
     break;

     case 500:
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-top" role="alert">' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<strong>500 Internal Server Error:</strong> The server encountered an error. Please try again.' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
     break;

     case 502:
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-top" role="alert">' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<strong>502 Bad Gateway:</strong> The server received an invalid response.' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
     break;

     case 504:
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-top" role="alert">' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<strong>504 Gateway Timeout:</strong> The server is taking too long to respond.' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
     break;
   }
 }
```

More or less I'm wondering why these two lines would stop my redirect script from working:

```
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN');
  header('Status: 403 You Do Not Have Access To This Page');
```

I did find a solution here that solved the redirect, but the error notification does not show: [How to send 500 Internal Server Error error from a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162223/how-to-send-500-internal-server-error-error-from-a-php-script)

Code based off of above selected answer:

```
// Redirect users from sensative pages
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] !== "admin") {
 $redirect[] = array();
 $redirect[] = "uploadImg.php";
 if (in_array(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), $redirect)) {
  header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 FORBIDDEN', true, 403);
  header("Location: index.php");
}
}
```

**OTHER ATTEMPTS:** I've also changed the following in an attempt to get my desired affect:

With the suggestion of @Parrot I tried:

```
// Redirect users from sensative pages
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] !== "admin") {
 $redirect[] = array();
 $redirect[] = "uploadImg.php";
 if (in_array(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), $redirect)) {
  http_response_code(403);
  header("Location: index.php");
}
}
```

Which didn't work to show the notification although it did redirect so this motivated me to change the top part of my error document to:

```
 if(isset($_GET['err'])) {
   $error_status = $_GET['err'];
 }
 else {
   $error_status = http_response_code();
 }
```

In the hope that it just wasn't originally reading the `http_response_code();`.

**NOTE:** I am also aware that I could just do `header("Location: index.php?err=403");` however I don't wish to show the error code in the address bar.

**NOTE:** I do know that my redirect method is not the most secure for protecting pages with sensitive information, however the pages I am redirecting from are just general pages that I do not wish view able by the general public.

Comment: Do you want `403` or `503`?

Comment: @Barmar `403 Forbidden` or `401 Unauthorized` but I'm aiming for `403`.

Comment: The question says "set a 503 header"

Comment: @Barmar whoops good catch. Updating.

Comment: U could set 403 is true inside session, redirect and show from session, if you don't mind the overhead. Controller would b a good place to check.

Comment: I thought about using sessions as a last ditch effort if all else failed.

Comment: Yes that is ugly though..

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

`header('HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN');
header('Status: 403 You Do Not Have Access To This Page');`

with:

`http_response_code(403);`
I think you don't need anything more :)

Comment: Added it in. The redirect works but unfortunately the notification doesn't appear. Which I know the script works because I tested it using `404` with a link that i knew didn't exist.